# Installed 17.04 alongside Windows 10 but now I cannot access Windows.

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, 17.04

I hope this isn't a duplicate question, I have had a look at some other threads but so far nothing has worked and I can't figure out what is going on!

I tried os-prober in terminal and /etc/default/grub but only get the response that permission is denied.

Is there anyway to check if windows 10 is still on my laptop and if so how can I get back into it?

I have installed dualboots before but this was the first time I had to contend with UEFI and I was wondering if that has messed something up?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Was Windows 10 UEFI or BIOS and then did you install Ubuntu in same mode? Some install options are full drive like the LVM with encryption and do erase everything. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! I followed the instructions for boot info and it generated this: http://paste2.org/mY9O9UhH so I hope that's correct! As far as I remember (apologies for not knowing exactly what I'm doing, I'm pretty bad at all this!) it was UEFI as the boot sequence was different form what I was used to. I disabled the UEFI to boot from an UBUNTU USB. During the installation process it did ask something about forcing the bios or grub (can't quite remember now!) and I chose to not force and keep the same option which it said was safer. I hope this info helps!

Comment: You may have UEFI hardware, but Ubuntu is installed in BIOS/CSM boot mode. And it looks like Windows was also in BIOS mode. Did you run `sudo update-grub` ? If so and you do not get Windows entry in grub menu, you probably left Windows hibernated or fast boot on. And Windows will kept turning it on with updates, and then grub will not boot Windows even if in menu. So you need to turn off after updates and know how to work around the issue when missed.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution! I updated grub, it found windows straight away and I have just booted into it! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, it is really appreciated :)

Comment: Just to really drive home how much of a noob I am... I can't seem to select your answer or give you any up votes or whatever! Thanks very much @oldfred

Comment: It not an answer, just a comment. Also suggest Windows repair disk and Ubuntu live installer always be available. Window will turn fast start on and then grub will not boot Windows. Then only fix is to temporarily restore Windows boot loader to MBR, and then reset/repair Windows. Then restore grub with Ubuntu live installer either manually or with Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System